# C# Coding Style - Fields

Tags: c#, coding-style

First of all, I don't want to start a coding styles war, so please only reply if you are answering the question.

I've encountered a couple of people who put their fields at the top of the class.  Could anyone who does this explain the rationale behind it?

Many thanks

Comment: I view fields (which are generally private) as the least important members of the class, so tuck them away by putting them at the very bottom. The reason for this is that once they're created I, generally, never touch them again. If I'm editing a class, then it's going to be either a constructor, method or property (if it isn't an auto-property) and, in my opinion, having fields at the top of the class is a pain because it means that you've got to scroll down to get to all of the other members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One rationale (at least before auto-properties came into existance) was to group all the state information at the top of the class because it goes a long way towards summarizing what the methods that follow will accomplish.

Answer (score 8):

I like to group fields at the top of a class only for code organizational purposes.  I find it easier to find what I'm looking for more quickly than if fields were spread out amongst the class.

I also typically group other members up by type and also have an internal sort by access modifier.

```
public class MyClass
{
    // Fields

    // Constructors

    // Properties

    // Methods
}
```

Comment: I agree, I find it easier to have the private fields defined in a #region at the top of the page

Comment: NO REGIONS! aaaaargh! If you use a region, Jeff Atwood will come round to your house!

Comment: I too group my members, although in a different order (Constructors, Methods, Properties then Fields) but, like you, I also subgroup them by access modifier. What I meant to ask was why put them at the top of the class instead of the bottom?

Comment: The reason I put them at the top is to give me a quick snapshot regarding the type of state information this given class is responsible for.  Even though automatic properties have eliminated many simple fields, i still find myself writing may properties with backing fields by hand.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not using Auto Properties I like to keep the backing store next to the property.  I like private state fields, static values, and constants, next constructors, then properties, followed by instance methods and then static methods.  If I have nested classes those either go to the top of the class if they are used by the entire class or right before the group of methods they are used with.

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public class MyNestedClass 
    {
    }

    // constants
    // private state fields
    // private static fields

    // constructors

    // properties
    // static properties

    // methods
    // static methods

    // finalizer if required
}
```

Comment: That's interesting and completely different to how I order my members.

Answer (score 1):

I put mine at the top of the class, because it causes the properties to cluster together, without the fields in between breaking them up.

But it's largely a matter of preference.  Intellisense insures that you always know what an identifier does, and "Go to definition" insures that it doesn't really matter where you put the fields.

Comment: I agree that it doesn't really matter, it is simply a matter of preference. The problem is when you have people working together who have very different preferences. To me, it's a pain having fields at the top (I put them at the bottom) and couldn't understand why people do. To be honest, I'm still not entirely clear why.

Comment: @stevenboy: That's what coding standards and conventions are for, to enforce a degree of uniformity within the code base. The correct standard is the one a given shop uses. When people put the fields at the top (rather than the bottom), they do it because it is logically consistent; fields should be defined before they are used.

Comment: "they do it because it is logically consistent; fields should be defined before they are used": That's a matter of opinion. If it were true, then the class wouldn't compile if you placed fields at the bottom. Anyway, I've now got a clear insight into why people put fields at the top. Thank you.